# how to turn off tomcat5 'session expire' log messages?

Tags: session, tomcat

I've been trying to turn off these excessive log messages without success.

```
 INFO   | jvm 1    | 2010/08/19 14:36:30 | DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] (ManagerBase.java:677) - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1282242990088 sessioncount 0
 INFO   | jvm 1    | 2010/08/19 14:36:30 | DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] (ManagerBase.java:685) - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
```

I added the following line to my app's WEB-INF/logging.properties file.

```
org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level=WARNING
```

Is this right? Is there somewhere else that I need to put it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following under `Tomcat/conf/logging.properties`:

```
org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = INFO
```

And as mentioned, verify that this is not being overwritten in your custom `log4j.properties` file.

This has worked for our team with *Tomcat v6.37* and *log4j1.2.13.jar*.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of ManagerBase.java, that seems to be the right setting

```
protected Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ManagerBase.class);
....
 if(log.isDebugEnabled())
  log.debug("Start expire sessions " 
      + getName() + " at " + timeNow + " sessioncount " + sessions.length);
```

I wonder if the `logging.properties` in the `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/` is overriding the one in the WEB-INF

Can you change it there as well?

Comment: thanks, i tried adding the line to the TOMCAT5/conf/logging.properties files but it did not take these entries out of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I put this in my logback.xml and it stopped the messages:

```
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase">
        <level value="INFO" />
</logger>
```