# Log Messages in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

I noticed that the `catalina.out` od Tomcat is getting populated with the `Start Expire Sessions` and `End expire sessions` as shown below.

```
Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1282242990088 sessioncount 0
End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
```

These messages are getting populated like 3-4 times every minute.

What do these messages exactly mean and is it suppose to log that often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to turn off tomcat5 'session expire' log messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525144/how-to-turn-off-tomcat5-session-expire-log-messages)

Comment: @Stefan : Thanks for the link, but is it suppose to be regularly adding these statements to the log, is it indicating any scenario.